# Using raycast2D and making player rotate to .hit preventing them from jumping

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Pretty much what the titles says. After adding this script to my player character:

```
    using System.Collections;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using UnityEngine;

    public class RotateHit : MonoBehaviour
    {
        public string Tag;
        public float offset;

        private Transform target;
        private Vector3 targetPos;
        private Vector3 thisPos;
        private float angle;

        void Start()
        {
            target = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag(Tag).GetComponent<Transform>();
        }

        void LateUpdate()
        {
            targetPos = target.position;
            thisPos = transform.position;
            targetPos.x = targetPos.x - thisPos.x;
            targetPos.y = targetPos.y - thisPos.y;
            angle = Mathf.Atan2(targetPos.y, targetPos.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
            transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(new Vector3(0, 0, angle + offset));
        }

    }
```

Whenever I press my jump key the sound effect plays but they don't move. If it matters I'm trying to add force to the rigidbody2D to make them jump.

My jump code:

```
        if (m_Grounded && jump)
        {
            m_Grounded = false;
            m_Rigidbody2D.AddForce(new Vector2(0f, m_JumpForce));
        }
```

```
    bool jump = false;

        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump"))
        {
                jump = true;
                FindObjectOfType<AudioManager>().Play("Jump");
        }
```

The code is split up because each part is in a different component.

Comment: Where is your jump code?

Comment: is your rigidbody kinematic? if so you can't add force

Comment: You probably already tried a much larger JumpForce, just to see if gravity pulls it down?

Comment: Where is `m_Grounded` set to true? Also, did you add debug in the `if (m_Grounded && jump)` part to ensure it's even getting called?